# How to Check If Function Even Page Reload

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have some function that run an ajax request.
For the first time I make a database insert before they click on that function.

```
INSERT INTO data_name (user_id, hash, status) VALUES ("1", "1a2b3c3d2e1f4g5h6i6j5k4", "closed");
```

And then I want to check with interval a JSON response that will update the database based on database "hash". If the response success then update the database WHERE hash = hash.

My problem is when I try to reload the page, the function is terminate also. How can I keep running the check function to see if JSON response changed to success even the page is reload or refresh.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: have you tried using `cookie` or `session`?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle your problem in the background. You can run a `crontab` job for your PHP script. Once you send a hash to server the scheduled script will do the checking.

Here is a way to set up a crontab job
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

This is something it should look like:

add_hush.php

```
...
$connection->query("INSERT INTO hashes (hash) VALUES ('1a2b3c3d2e1f4g5h6i')");
...
```

check_hash.php

```
...

$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM hashes");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $connection->query('INSERT INTO data_name (user_id, hash, status) VALUES ("1", "' . $row["hash"]  . '", "closed")';

    $connection->query("DELETE FROM hushes WHERE hush=" . $row["hush"]);
}
...
```

The add_hush.php will call from your ajax request. Then the check_hash.php will be a call from the cronjob.

This is how you call a PHP script from cronjob:

`* * * * * /your/project/folder/check_hash.php`

Comment: How to send the hash data to the cronjob through php?